# Find a way to query a list of items that meet ALL of a criteria using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to do the following:

```
select i.FirstName, i.LastName, COUNT(1) from (
    select u.Id, uw.WidgetId from [DB].[dbo].[Widgets] w inner join
     UserWidgets uw on w.Id = uw.WidgetId inner join
     Users u on uw.UserId = u.Id
     where uw.WidgetId in ('29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44', 
                           'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418',
                          'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655')
     group by u.Id, uw.WidgetId
     ) a
 inner join [Db2].[dbo].[Identities] i on a.Id = i.IdentityId
 group by i.LastName, i.FirstName
 order by i.LastName, i.FirstName
```

What I want is to ensure that the "In" statement requires that the User ONLY has those 3 Id's.  No more, no less.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: A question: do they have to have all three IDs?

Comment: To understand the question, the user must have exactly three widgets and those three widgets must have the widget id's listed in your IN clause, correct?

Comment: The operator you require is 'relational division' e.g. http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select i.FirstName, i.LastName, COUNT(1) from (
    select u.Id, uw.WidgetId from [DB].[dbo].[Widgets] w inner join
     UserWidgets uw on w.Id = uw.WidgetId 
                    and uw.WidgetId in ('29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44', 
                           'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418',
                          'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655')
     inner join Users u on uw.UserId = u.Id
     left join UserWidgets uw2 on uw2.userid = u.id
                    and uw2.WidgetId not in ('29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44', 
                           'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418',
                          'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655')
     where uw2.widgetid is null
     group by u.Id, uw.WidgetId
     ) a
 inner join [Db2].[dbo].[Identities] i on a.Id = i.IdentityId
 group by i.LastName, i.FirstName
 having count(1) = 3
 order by i.LastName, i.FirstName
```

Comment: Unless my friday afternoon beer filled brain is wrong, which it may be, I think your query is going to return items with one, two or three of the GUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

```
    select i.FirstName, i.LastName, COUNT(1) from (
    select u.Id, uw.WidgetId from [DB].[dbo].[Widgets] w inner join
     UserWidgets uw on w.Id = uw.WidgetId inner join
     Users u on uw.UserId = u.Id
     where uw.WidgetId in ('29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44', 
                           'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418',
                          'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655')
     AND count(WidgetId) = 3
     group by u.Id, uw.WidgetId
     ) a
 inner join [Db2].[dbo].[Identities] i on a.Id = i.IdentityId
 group by i.LastName, i.FirstName
 order by i.LastName, i.FirstName
```

I added the 'AND count(WidgetId) = 3' in to the query...i believe that would work?

Comment: You can't use an aggregate statement in the `where` clause and you aren't checking to see if the user has any other IDs.

Comment: You're right Allan.  I should have HAVING count(uw.WidgetId) = 3 after the group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT i.firstname,
       i.lastname,
       COUNT(1)
FROM   (SELECT u.id,
               uw.widgetid
        FROM   [DB].[dbo].[Widgets] w
               INNER JOIN userwidgets uw
                 ON w.id = uw.widgetid
               INNER JOIN users u
                 ON uw.userid = u.id
        WHERE  uw.widgetid IN ( '29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44',
                                        'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418'
                                        ,
                                'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655' )
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                               FROM   [DB].[dbo].[Widgets] w2
                                      INNER JOIN userwidgets uw2
                                        ON w2.id = uw2.id
                               WHERE  w2.id = w.id
                                      AND uw2.widgetid NOT IN (
                              '29017318-FD89-4952-A3A2-8405BD5C5C44',
                              'BDB7D25C-0794-4965-842D-E6D03A250418'
                              ,
                              'CB4553AC-A47B-4AA6-9231-5C59C8F97655' ))
        GROUP  BY u.id,
                  uw.widgetid) a
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT uw.widgetid) = 3
       INNER JOIN [Db2].[dbo].[Identities] i
         ON a.id = i.identityid
GROUP  BY i.lastname,
          i.firstname
ORDER  BY i.lastname,
          i.firstname
```

Comment: Add `having count(distinct uw.widgetid) = 3` to the innermost query will ensure that it has all three IDs.

Comment: You've got it in the wrong spot.  It needs to be with `GROUP  BY u.id, uw.widgetid`, but you've put it in the `exists` query.