# mysql - Get count of items where status of ALL sub-items meet the criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a hard time coming up with a title for this question, but I think it may be easy for someone who is an SQL guru.

Tables:

```
SIMULATION: ID, SIMULATION_SET_ID, EXECUTION_STATUS
SIMULATION_SET: SET_ID 
SIMULATION_BATCH: ID
BATCH_ELEMENT: SIMULATION_BATCH_ID, SIMULATION_SET_ID
```

(In words, a set contains a bunch of simulations.  A batch contains a bunch of sets via an intermediate table.  The Batch is really a meta-container to group sets based on when they are requested, and are used as a container, but don't themselves contain a status.)

I am trying to return a count of completed batches, and a completed batch would be one in which all of the simulations have an execution status of COMPLETED.  However, I seem to be getting any batch that any completed simulation, even if they all aren't.  This was my attempt:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) 
FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION S ON S.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
WHERE S.EXECUTION_STATUS ='COMPLETED'";
```

So after looking back I see this doesn't work.  I tried to add in a AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT...) clause to try to rule out batches that had simulations where the execution status was not completed, but that didn't work at all, it consistently returned an empty set when anything was running.  This is what I added:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT SIM.ID 
FROM SIMULATION SIM 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE2 ON BE2.SIMULATION_SET_ID=SIM.SIMULATION_SET_ID  
WHERE BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID AND SIM.EXECUTION_STATUS != 'COMPLETED' );
```

Thanks for any insight into this.   I think I need to better learn subqueries but I'm not sure.  After I figure out how to get a count, I need to get a list of the batches with a bunch of info about them, but I think I can do that if I can get a count.

Update:  I've been working on this all day, haven't made that much progress except more wrong ones.  I was thinking an easier way to describe what I'm looking for is I want Batches where ALL Simulations in the batch meet some criteria (like status is omplete).   I can do this when ANY (at least 1) Simulation meets the criteria, but it's the ALL that seems to be throwing me.   Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some sample data? Honestly, your query looks like it should work...

Comment: I will see if I can get example data.  What happened with the not exists clause is I got a count of 0 when simulations were running, and a full count when they were all completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see a typo/bug in the subquery that explains why the overall query "consistently returned an empty set when anything was running."

See this line of your subquery:

```
WHERE BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID AND SIM.EXECUTION_STATUS != 'COMPLETED' );
```

I think you meant to have this instead:

```
WHERE BE2.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID AND SIM.EXECUTION_STATUS != 'COMPLETED' );
```

If that fixes the problem, then you could also try simplifying the query with something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) 
FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT SIM.ID
    FROM SIMULATION SIM
    INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE2 ON BE2.SIMULATION_SET_ID=SIM.SIMULATION_SET_ID  
    WHERE BE2.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID AND 
    SIM.EXECUTION_STATUS != 'COMPLETED' );
```

This assumes that:

1. A batch always has at least one batch element.
2. A batch element always has at least one simulation.

It looks like the first case is true since you wrote, "The batch_element record is inserted when the batch is created." But I'm not sure about the second one.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and let you know, it has been driving me crazy but then I was sick for a few days.  If you are right about the typo, I will bang my head against the wall, because then I was on the right track, just had one logic mistake

Comment: Well, that worked, and I think you found my bug.  So I guess that's why everyone here said it looked like it should work, it was just one little mistake.  Your solution is cleaner though.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why your `NOT EXISTS` wouldn't have worked, but here's a slightly different approach:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT B.ID) 
FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION S ON 
    S.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID AND 
    S.EXECUTION_STATUS ='COMPLETED'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM SIMULATION SUBSIM 
    WHERE 
        SUBSIM.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
        AND SUBSIM.EXECUTION_STATUS != 'COMPLETED'
)
```

(The CAPS is a little hard on my eyes, but I wanted to keep your convention...)

Comment: Ha, about the CAPS.  I guess I'm old school when it comes to database stuff, plus since it has to run on Windows and Linux/Unix, it's just safer.  I will try these modifications and see what happens.  Thanks for your input, I will let you know what happens

Comment: Ok, I tried this one, and what I get is this.  When I know that all of the batches are completed, I get a count of 19.   Then I kick off a new batch, and I get a count of 19 (good so far).  But as soon as one simulation in the batch completes, even though 23 others haven't, I get a count of 20.  Maybe the whole way I'm trying it is just wrong.  Apparently since it's not working!

Comment: @titania424 So does the batch that has 23 simulations still in process have `batch_element` records for all the simulations that haven't yet completed?  Or does the `batch_element` record only get added when a simulation is completed?

Comment: The batch_element record joins the Batch and the set.  Each simulation belongs to one set.  The batch_element record is inserted when the batch is created.  I was just thinking maybe I need a temp table or equivalent (since I need to do a similar query of completed batches, but get summary data about them, like the number of simulations in them and duration based on the start/end times of each simulation).

Comment: So basically a batch has a bunch of sets, those are kept track of via the batch_element table.   Then a set has a bunch of simulations.  I am trying to figure out the status of a batch by looking at all the simulations.  It's actually a little more complicated than what I've said because there are many statuses, but I'm looking at completed as a means to solve them all.  So I'm wondering if I need a temp table (or however you do it) to get a join of the batches and their simulations, then select from that to see if all simulations in a batch are completed.

Comment: What's the `EXECUTION_STATUS` of the simulations that are running? Is it `NULL`?  Basically, the query in the `NOT EXISTS` isn't finding any of the simulations in the batch that aren't yet completed... if we can figure out why it isn't finding them, then we'll fix the problem.

Comment: The status of the ones that aren't completed can be a whole bunch of other ones.  I have another query that gets the batch summaries of all the batches, and that seems to work, I can show you that one.  My goal is for that one to also get the batch summaries for only the completed ones, not all of them.  I was wondering if the Select should be from the Simulation table instead, maybe?

Comment: I just ran some other tests and queries, and it seems when it finds any simulations with that status, it still has a row in the results.  Like if there were 7 running, and 1 complete, there was still 1 row in the results representing the one complete.  Banging my head against the wall here, I know there has to be a solution!  It's easy to find when there exists ANY that meet a set of statuses, but not easy to say ALL must equal the status.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT B.ID 
FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION S ON S.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION SC ON SC.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
WHERE SC.EXECUTION_STATUS ='COMPLETED'"
GROUP BY B.ID
HAVING COUNT(S.ID) = COUNT(SC.ID)) AS COMPLETED_BATCHES;
```

Join SIMULATION twice and filter one (SC) on EXECUTION_STATUS. The HAVING clause says we only want rows where the number simulations equals the number of completed simulations.

EDIT: For debugging, this query should give you a feel for how it works:

```
SELECT B.ID, COUNT(S.ID) AS SIMULATION_COUNT, COUNT(SC.ID) AS COMPLETED_SIM_COUNT
FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION S ON S.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
INNER JOIN SIMULATION SC ON SC.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
WHERE SC.EXECUTION_STATUS ='COMPLETED'"
GROUP BY B.ID
```

You could even use it for the sub-query, skip the HAVING, and do:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM (
  SELECT B.ID, COUNT(S.ID) AS SIMULATION_COUNT, COUNT(SC.ID) AS COMPLETED_SIM_COUNT
  FROM SIMULATION_BATCH B 
  INNER JOIN BATCH_ELEMENT BE ON BE.SIMULATION_BATCH_ID=B.ID 
  INNER JOIN SIMULATION S ON S.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
  INNER JOIN SIMULATION SC ON SC.SIMULATION_SET_ID=BE.SIMULATION_SET_ID 
  WHERE SC.EXECUTION_STATUS ='COMPLETED'"
  GROUP BY B.ID
) AS COUNTED_BATCHES
WHERE SIMULATION_COUNT = COMPLETED_SIM_COUNT;
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.  I saw some other examples with "HAVING" and I confess to not knowing how to do this.  I'm only masquerading as a database person, having to do a bit of everything on a small project.  Will update here after I try it.

Comment: UPDATE, ok, it didn't work, as soon as there exists one simulation with COMPLETED status, the number of batches came back incremented.  I think this is close though and I will keep trying.

Comment: I saw this example with a having, but they use some left joins also.  Problem is I have no idea what they are doing!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352461/find-a-way-to-query-a-list-of-items-that-meet-all-of-a-criteria-using-sql

Comment: A left join will return rows on the LEFT that don't have a match on the right. I this case, it would bring back SIMULATION_BATCH records that don't have any SIMULATIONS. See my edited ans for some debugging fun.

Comment: Thanks - on that first one, I added DISTINCT for both counts, because otherwise it was giving crazy numbers.  With the DISTINCT that one seems to give correct counts.  So that's good.  I know I'm getting close.  Trying the second one now.